# How to copy a cells value if another cell is not blank in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Original Explaination:

I'm looking for some help please. I have a form that logs new content requests, and I want it to return a expected completion date. Currently, I have the queue in a separate tab, with queue length calculated based on a countif False for content being completed.

If column one, sheet 1 (New Requests) is not blank, I need it to copy and paste the current value in sheet 2, cell A1 (The current queue length), into sheet 1, column 2. Each new form response will affect the queue length, so I'd need this to be pasted as values.

Basically, I need IF Sheet1columnA<>Blank, copy-paste as values Sheet2A1 into Sheet1ColumnB, but I'm still figuring out app script so any help would be great please!

Let me know if you need any further information

UPDATE:
Not yet resolved, but here is where I've gotten to:

```
  function attempt() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(" removed due to data protection ");
  let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("New Requests");
  let sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Current Queue");
   var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
 // Iterates request by each row
 data.forEach(function (row) {
// First check if column I is blank
   if (row[8].isblank){
// then, if column A is not blank
   if (!row[0].isBlank()){
// copy Current Queue A1
     let valToPaste = sheet2.getrange(1,1).getValue();
// defines where to paste - This is where I'm struggling
     sheet1.getrange(row[8]).setValue(valToPaste)
   };
 });
}
}
```

Effectively, I want it for each row in "New Requests", to check if column I is blank, and if so, check if column A is not blank. If A is not blank, the current value in "Current Queue" A1 is to be pasted into column I.

Let me know your thoughts, I think I'm getting close here!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by using a script similar to this:

```
function copyVals() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  let colA = sheet1.getRange('A:A');
  if (!colA.isBlank()) {
    let valToPaste = sheet2.getRange(1,1).getValue();
    sheet1.getRange(1,2).setValue(valToPaste);
  }
}
```

In order to check if the wanted column is not empty, the `isBlank` method has been used. If the condition checks, the `valToPaste`, which represents the value from `Sheet2!A1` is pasted into `Sheet2!B1`.

#### Note

- You may need to add a `for` loop, depending on your exact needs.
- Since you mentioned you are using a form, you may want to check [Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class - isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank).

Comment: Thank you for this, this has given me a good starting point - Currently, the script is only adding to the top cell in the target sheet, would it be the for loop you mentioned to get around that?

Comment: Yes! And you would have to modify the range from `getRange` as well in order to match the current range :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to run through this tutorial for how to loop it through rows and the formula works for the logger function, but I'm struggling to mix the above with it: https://spreadsheet.dev/iterate-through-rows-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script

I think my issue is defining the ranges - How would I define the range for just the columns on the current row? I've been trying to google it but not sure I know enough to phrase the question correctly.. Thanks again for your help though @ale13 , I think I'm getting somewhere!

Comment: Assuming you're using a for loop smth similar to `for(let i=0; i<length; i++)`, you can call `getRange(i+1,1)` which will yield you the range for `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and so on. I suggest you make use of the `getRange` method and take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) since you can pass multiple parameters to it.

Comment: thank you as always! Unfortunately I'm still struggling - I'm brand new to app script and may have bitten off more than I can chew for my first foray into coding! I've added my attempt to my original post, along with descriptors of what I am understanding each row to be doing. I was attempting to use a forEach so that I could have it run through each row, where would I go from here? Thank you so much again, I really appreciate you taking the time to help a true newbie like myself!